# How to force device detection and diagnose issues

Tags: wireless, internet, hardware, nic

I'm using an Acer Aspire V3 571G. It originally had Windows 7 installed but after sustaining some physical trauma it became unable to boot, judging by the scratching sound one of the hard drive's read/write arms had become slightly displaced.

Using a friend's computer I made a bootable USB, made the malfunctioning parts of the HDD inaccessible and installed Ubuntu Desktop. Unfortunately the WLAN0 NIC isn't being detected (no switch is visible).

How can I rectify this? I should also point out ethernet is not an option for downloading utilities (I'm writing this on my phone).

The end goal is either connecting to the internet or confirming I need a new NIC.